# How to join a table returned in a SQL operation with another table?

Tags: postgresql

I would like to filter table X and then use an `INNER JOIN` to return a table which contains columns from table X and table Y. Here is the PostgreSQL code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION player_data.GetAllTransactions(playerId INTEGER, transactionDate DATE)
RETURNS TABLE(id BIGINT, created_date TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE, financial_transaction_type_id SMALLINT, amount NUMERIC)
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS
$$
DECLARE
    
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY SELECT db.x.id, db.x.created_date, db.x.trans_type, db.x.amount 
    FROM db.x
    WHERE db.x.created_date::DATE=transactionDate;
    -- INNER JOIN db.y ON db.y.id=db.x.wallet_id WHERE db.y.player_id=playerId;
END;
$$
```

I am trying to take the table from the `SELECT` statement and join it with the `INNER JOIN` statement. How can I achieve this?

Comment: try put the command into a variable and execute the variable. declare _query text; select 'select now();' into _query;
EXECUTE _query;

Comment: Put the inner join before the `WHERE` clause, then it should work. Why a PL/pgSQL function for that?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I'm still new to PGSQL and taking the opportunity to get accustomed to writing functions. This function will grow with functionality.